# sharepoint 2013 list datetime picker select year

Tags: sharepoint, datepicker, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, jquerydatetimepicker

I want to add year option in sharepoint list datepicker column, since it does not allow to pick year except to swap 12 months back can someone suggest somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No option for this, use [jQuery Datapicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) instead.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    })
```

Update:

Insert the script into your list form(new forum/edit form),update the "Time" as your field title.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[title="Time"]').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            })
            $('input[title="Time"]').parent().siblings().hide();
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: how to add to my datepicker column